# Keycloak: How to override Welcome Screen redirect behavior (to custom realm, instead of master realn/admin)

Tags: nginx, keycloak

I am using Keycloak (`24.0.2`) as a standalone self-registration app (with some custom fields) for a small non-profit organization. Keycloak runs as docker behind nginx and is served under `keycloak.myorganization.com`. I have two realms: `master` (the default one) and `members` (where members will login/register).

Now, I would like to have users automatically forwarded to the "members" login/registration upon entering the base path. I set `Frontend URL` for the master realm to `keycloak.myorganization.com` and to `members.myorganization.com` for the members realm.

I also modified the docker environment variables:

```
KC_HOSTNAME=members.myorganization.com
KC_HOSTNAME_ADMIN=keycloak.myorganization.com
```

Nginx does the SSL termination and uses `proxy_pass` to forward everything to localhost/docker for both `members.myorganization.com` and `keycloak.myorganization.com`.

However, when I open https://members.myorganization.com, I get forwarded to the admin/root console, not the members realm login, which is available under https://members.myorganization.com/realms/members/account/.

How can I directly forward https://members.myorganization.com to https://members.myorganization.com/realms/members/account/ ?

In the [Migration Guide](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/upgrading/index.html), it says:

> If the Admin Console is enabled, the welcome page will automatically redirect to it if the administrative user already exists. This behavior can be modified by setting the `redirectToAdmin` in your `theme.properties` file. By default, the property is set to `false`, unless you are extending the built-in theme, in which case, the property is set to `true`.

Does this mean I will have to create/override the theme to modify the redirect behavior?

Comment: I see the question was tagged with MongoDB Realm, can you update the question as to how it pertains to MongoDB Realm, the database? If so, which SDK are you using?

Comment: This has nothing to do with MongoDB. There is no MongoDB tag and I am not using any SDK. I am using Keycloak with docker. Edit: I see: This is not the Realm from Mongo DB (keycloak also uses "realm"). I removed that tag. Apologies.